# How to make array element to string using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array element like this,

```
$array = array(rha3pf, rha3pf, adfsasdf, asdfsad);
```

I want to make a unique, for that i used,

```
$uniqe = array_unique($array);
print_r($uniqe);
```

I want result as,

```
$array = array(rha3pf, adfsasdf, asdfsad);
```

I am getting result as,

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant rha3pf - assumed 'rha3pf' --  at line 3
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant rha3pf - assumed 'rha3pf' -- at line 3
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant adfsasdf - assumed 'adfsasdf' -- at line 3
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant asdfsad - assumed 'asdfsad' -- at line 3
Array ( [0] => rha3pf [2] => adfsasdf [3] => asdfsad )
```

I am not getting correct answer in live. How to solve this

Thanks in advances

Comment: shouldn't it be like `print_r($uniqe)`?

Comment: You need to `print_r($uniqe)` instead of `print_r($a);`

Comment: Hi, there's just a typo in your code... the last line should be `print_r($uniqe);`

Comment: Sorry i have worngly edited that content, I have edit my questions

Comment: @Vijaykarthik what do you want as your output?

Comment: Hi @Pankit Kapadia, I want to remove same value in an array that was "rha3pf". But my output was "Use of undefined constant rha3pf - assumed 'rha3pf'" How to make my array as string, Because i am dyanamically getting value

Comment: See the difference [**your code**](https://3v4l.org/rkDub) and [**updated code**](https://3v4l.org/RBPlK)

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
$array = array('rha3pf', 'rha3pf', 'adfsasdf', 'asdfsad');
$a = implode(" ",$array);
$a = array_unique($a);
print_r($a);
```

will print

```
rha3pf adfsasdf asdfsad
```

Answer (score -1):

What is `$a` in print??

```
<?php
 $array = array(rha3pf, rha3pf, adfsasdf, asdfsad);
 $uniqe = array_unique($array);
 print_r($uniqe);
       //^^^ this part  
?>
```

Working demo [here](https://eval.in/476842)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my result was still like Array ( [0] => rha3pf [1] => rha3pf [2] => adfsasdf [3] => asdfsad ). I have tried in phpfiddle I am getting error like this "E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant rha3pf - assumed 'rha3pf' -- at line 2" Can you say solution for this=

Comment: did u check the demo??

Comment: Yes in demo its working, but in my web page i am getting error like this "Use of undefined constant rha3pf - assumed 'rha3pf'"

Comment: See the difference [**your code**](https://3v4l.org/rkDub) and [**updated code**](https://3v4l.org/RBPlK)

Comment: @Uchiha, same code is working here, but Op is getting error, thank you for this.

Comment: @Vijaykarthik check the updated code from uchiha in the comment.

Comment: Yes bro, i was checked. but my array list was came from my database like this  rha3pf, rha3pf, adfsasdf, asdfsad How to give quotation for every element in array list. I want result as removed dublicate value from the above array list